# Trennbare Verben: er sieht aus wie... oder er sieht wie... aus

Tags: colloquial, separable-verb

Today in a German course I read:

> Er sieht aus wie ein Monster.

Shouldn't it always be with the separable part in the end? i.e.:

> Er sieht wie ein Monster aus.

In spoken German I hear it quite often though: is it not considered incorrect then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are constructions of varying "weight" in the language, and depending on how "weighty" a sentence part is, an exposition beyond the *Verbklammer* becomes more or less acceptable.

Normal objects are pretty lightweight and should always stay inside the *Verbklammer*:

> Ich giesse den Eimer aus.
>
> *Ich giesse aus den Eimer.

Adverbial modifications are usually also supposed to stay inside:

> Ich steige aus der Produktion aus.
>
> ?Ich steige aus aus der Produktion.

Heavyweight constructions such as a relative clause are actually *preferred* outside:

> Ich fange einen Roman an, der von der Entwicklung der Sonate im französischen Barock handelt.
>
> ?Ich fange einen Roman, der von der Entwicklung der Sonate im französischen Barock handelt, an.

Constructions with "wie" are (to me) right in the middle of this sliding scale of weightiness - both sound equally fine to me:

> Er sieht aus wie ein Monster.
>
> Er sieht wie ein Monster aus.

Comment: Was bedeutet `*?`?

Answer (score 4):

Both sentences are correct and at first glance I wanted to say that they are equal. But there is a significant difference in stress and - as a consequence - the two sentence convey a different rate of determination.

While

> Er sieht *aus* wie ein Monster [oder wie ein Zwerg oder wie ein Serienmörder].

is stressed on the *aus*, emphasizing that he looks weird in some way and the 'Monster' is more or less an example,

whereas

> Er sieht wie ein *Monster* aus [und nicht wie etwas anderes].

is stressed on the *Monster*, making this particular choice unambiguous and determined.

Answer (score 0):

@Stefan Schoeder. Für mich liegt die Haupt-Betonung in beiden Fällen auf *'Monster'*. Ein betontes *'aus'* gäb's für mich in einem Satz wie *'wie siehst du wieder aus!'* (= *'wie läufst du heute wieder rum!'*). Allerdings würde ich zustimmen, dass das '*aus*' in '*er sieht aus wie ein Monster*' einen Nebenton trägt.